# Not able to see localized images in iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have an existing working iPhone project inside XCode 4.2. I localized an image (which is used on a button) and I always see the old version of it inside the iPhone simulator. Where does it find that old version?

What I've done:

1. Window -> Organizer -> Project -> Delete Derived Data
2. Product -> Clean
3. Inside the IPhone simulator, I tried resetting it.
4. I tried deleting the project and recreating it (from SVN)
5. I deleted everything in Library->Developer->Xcode, Library->Delveoper->Application Support->iPhone simulator, Library->Developer->Application->Interface Builder 3.0

And I still see the old version... Is it compiled somewhere inside the interface builder with the button or something like that? Weird... really weird.

Note: I'm able to localize an image button if I add a new image, but using old existing image is always showing me the old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution :**
My project contained images like ImageName@2x.png (for IPad I guess).
By also localizing those + clean + build + reset IPhone Sim settings, it worked. Go figure.

Also, when I add another language for the @2x images, I have to manually add the image in the other xx.lproj (where XX is the language code) with the finder because somehow XCode doesn't it.

Comment: I found this also works if you are working with CoreData and made a change to the XCDataModel (when database migration is not needed of course)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the App in iPhone Simulator (same way you would delete it on real iPhone) and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem to this where the XIB file would not accept modifications.  I eventually fixed by renaming the XIB file and then changes were accepted.  Worth a try in your case I think.

Comment: The project doesn't compile after that :(  (I'm a newbie to XCode and MACs). But, by renaming images, deleting the buttons, recreating the buttons and using the new renamed image, it works. I really wonder where he's finding the old image, I even searched on all my HD and just found the 2 normal instances of the file (english en french)

Comment: Ah yes, the @2x images got you!  Those are actually for the retina display (iPhone 4 in other words) so that's undoubtedly what you were seeing!  Didn't think of that.